# What is the proper constructor for a vector of lists

Tags: c++, oop, vector, constructor

I was looking at some of the examples on how to make a proper constructor for vectors and im still confused on how to actually implement one.  Using the given class...

```
class Graph
{
private:
    class Edge
    {
    public:
        Edge(string vertex, int weight)
        {
            m_vertex = vertex;
            m_weight = weight;
        }
        ~Edge(){}
        string m_vertex;
        int m_weight;
    };
    vector< list<Edge> > adjList; //vector of lists
public:
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    vector < list < Edge > > get_adjList(){return adjList;}
    //Other functions....

};
```

I am still not sure what to put in the constructor `Graph::Graph()`  I have tried doing a few things such as

```
Graph::Graph()
{
    new vector < list < Edge > >;
}
```

But I was told this causes a memory leak.  Ive only ever made constructors for linked lists before and never needed one for vectors until now.  I could use some clarity on how to make a constructor for a vector of lists.  I need the constructor so I can access adjList (the vector of lists) in other files in order to copy it.

Comment: Your `new` statement causes a memory leak because it constructs a `vector< list< Edge > >` but doesn't capture the pointer to it anywhere.  It just throws it away.  The `adjList` member in your class gets allocated for you when you allocate a `Graph`, so there's no need to `new` a separate one in your constructor.

Comment: I'm also skeptical that your `get_adjList()` should return a fresh new copy of `adjList`.  It seems like it ought to be returning a reference to the one inside `Graph`.  That is, it seems like its return type should be `vector< list< Edge > >&`.

Comment: +1 comment @JoeZ .. I was wondering the same thing

Comment: You really need to familiarize yourself with the difference between value and reference semantics. STL classes vector/list/etc follow value semantics.

Comment: oh, and your edges dont seem to contain any info out who they connect to, that seems to make them useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Graph` already has a member `vector< list< Edge > > adjList` that gets allocated and constructed for you when you construct a `Graph`.  You don't need to write any further constructor.

The call to `new` here can be completely deleted:

```
Graph::Graph()
{
    new vector < list < Edge > >;  // DELETE THIS LINE
}
```

As it stands, it allocates an entirely separate `vector< list< Edge > >` and then throws away the pointer returned by `new`.  But, from all appearances, you didn't need it anyway.  Your `adjList` member is already there, empty and waiting for data.  You didn't need to call `new` or anything.

What you *do* need is some way to populate the `adjList` member.  You could do that within `Graph::Graph()` or from code outside.

Your current getter function, `get_adjList()` currently returns a *copy* of `adjList`, not a reference.  You might consider changing that method to return a reference:

```
vector < list < Edge > >& get_adjList() {return adjList;}
```

Or a pointer:

```
vector < list < Edge > >* get_adjList() {return &adjList;}
```

so that code outside the class can call `get_adjList()` and then manipulate the field inside the class.

Something like this:

```
Graph my_graph;

vector< list<Edge> >& adjList = my_graph.get_adjList();

// Make a graph with two nodes, both pointing at each other, with weight 10
adjList.resize( 2 );  // make room for two nodes
adjList[0].push_back( Edge( 1, 10 ) );
adjList[1].push_back( Edge( 0, 10 ) );
```

To keep your fingers from falling off typing `vector< list<Edge> >` over and over, you can add a `typedef` inside `class Graph`:

```
class Graph
{
    public:
        typedef vector< list< Edge > > adj_type;

    // ...
};
```

And then outside, you could say something like:

```
Graph::adj_type& adjList = my_graph.get_adjList();
```

That also insulates the rest of the code from the exact definition of `adj_type` should you change it later.

You should eventually consider adding methods to `Graph` to add vertices and edges.  Something like:

```
class Graph
{
    //...
    public:
        void add_vertex( unsigned id )
        {
            if (id > adjList.size() )
                adjList.resize( id );
        }

        void add_edge( unsigned from_id, unsigned to_id, int weight )
        {
            adjList[fromId].push_back( Edge( to_id, weight ) );
        }
 }
```

Untested code, but you get the idea, hopefully.

One last thought:  Why is `m_vertext` a string in `Edge`?  I just noticed that and it seems very odd.

If your vertices are non-numeric, then you should consider using a `map< string, list<Edge> >` in place of a `vector` for your `adjList`.  Or add a `map<string, unsigned>` to map strings to IDs.  Otherwise you won't be able to efficiently chase your edges to vertices.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, I already have functions in Graph.cpp that perfectly populate the adjList and can even print out the entire vector of lists without seg faulting.

Comment: @user3040019 : Given a vertex, can you walk through the edges, and then visit the vertices named by those edges?  How do you convert from `m_vertex` that's a string back to something you can index `adjList` with?  Are you doing a bunch of string to integer conversions?

Comment: Heres how the program will work in the end, Its practice with implementing Prim's algorithm.  I make an adjacency list.. `(A,0)->(B,2)->(C,3)` etc.. then I will remove a single vector of lists from `adjList` and convert it into `[Nil, A, 0][A,B,2][A,C,3]` ([predecessorVertex, Vertex, Weight], place it into a min priority queue and run Prim's algorithm.  I will then repeat this until the entire adjacency list is empty.

Comment: @user3040019: I'm asking a simpler question:  Given an Edge `e`, and `e.m_vertex`, how do you look up that vertex in `vector< list< Edge > >`, given that `e.m_vertex` is `std::string`, but `adjList` is indexed by integers?

Comment: I'm having trouble explaining that, probably because I dont have to do much in the program (it takes inputs and immediately goes to output without needing commands).  I'm sorry, the reason I am having trouble with this stuff is because my teacher never taught us about complex data handling, she just assumed we already knew it. (even though we didn't learn about it last semester)

Comment: I guess All i can say now is that the vector represents the Vertices and the lists represent what is adjacent to each vertex.  Sorry I cant answer your question.

Comment: @user3040019 : The way I've usually represented edge lists like this is to either give each vertex an integer ID (which you could then use directly as an index to `vector< ... > adjList`), or a direct pointer.  Since you're using `vector<>`, the integer ID route makes a lot of sense.  Storing vertex names as strings is overkill.  If you need to relate them back to human-friendly strings, build a couple maps to translate back and forth when you need to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43649/discussion-between-joe-z-and-user3040019)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `new`, `adjList` is already a `vector` variable on stack if you make an instance of `Graph` (this is not Java) and I think the default vector constructor is enough, no need to call it explicitely. You need to call `new` only if your variable is a pointer.

But you may have to change the return type of `get_adjList` to just return reference of `adjList`, not a new copy of `adjList`.

```
class Graph
{
private:
    vector<list<Edge> > adjList; //vector of lists
public:
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    vector<list<Edge> > &get_adjList(){return adjList;}
};
```

Or maybe if what you need is actually the `vector` element, better not to return `vector`, just return the element based on a query index, for example:

```
list<Edge> &get_adjListElmt(int idx){return adjList[idx];}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your graph class can read from a file, then your constructor for the class could look something like:

```
Graph::Graph(istream &iss)
{
    // number of vertices in the graph
    // where each vertex has a list of edges
    size_t vertices;
    iss >> vertices;
    adjList.resize(vertices);
    ...
}
```

Other than setting the size of the vector, there is no need to dynamically allocate space for a vector unless you declare the vector as a pointer in your class.

Now as for getting access to the vector, you can create a getter method in your class that returns a copy of the vector (if you do not wish for the original to be mutated) or the getter can return a reference/pointer to the actual object

I have implemented a graph class a while back and another option you might want to look into is a constructor that can create a random graph object given `density`, `maxedgeLength`, and `numberofvertices`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @joe-z. However, I think the issue might be that he needs a vector of a certain size.

```
struct Edge {  // you could template this to make more generic.
    int v2;
    double weight;
};
class Graph {
public:
    Graph(size_t size) : m_adj_list(size) {}
    void AddEdge(int v1, int v2, double weight) {
        m_adj_list[v1].emplace_back(v2, weight);
    }
    void Resize(size_t size) {
        m_adj_list.resize(size, std::vector<Edge>());
    }
private:
    // You can use a list but in general a vector might be a better choice
    std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> m_adj_list;
};
```

In addition. Don't just use bare pointers. Use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr. In general you can use the rule (in this order):

1. do not use pointers (std::vector already takes care of your memory management)
2. use a unique_ptr
3. use a shared_ptr
4. use a bare pointer when not taking/representing ownership and you can't pass a shared_ptr around